# Scenario with duplicate steps - how can I write up or override this?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, gherkin

I have a test that I am trying to automate for work that I will replicate steps - Opening the settings/closing the settings window

Writing in python - given when then gherkin language

```
 Feature: Global Visibility Settings (TCOE-T16)

  Background:
    Given I open a browser
    Then I select an Event
    And I open Global Visibility Settings

   Scenario:
     Then I toggle CDIF slider off
   Scenario:
     Then I toggle CDIF slider on
```

I've tried to see if there is a possibility of doing like a background scenario for the test - but this is the only test cases that I am writing up that will go in and out of the global visibility settings bc I am verifying the toggle buttons can be turned off/on
I've tried to write the feature file to open settings toggle button - close window - open settings toggle button back on - close window

```
 Feature: Global Visibility Settings (TCOE-T16)

  Background:
    Given I open a browser
    Then I select an Event

   Scenario:
     And I open Global Visibility Settings
     Then I toggle CDIF slider off
     And close window
     And open Global Visibility Settings
     Then I toggle CDIF slider on
```

Comment: What I'm trying to do is write up a test that will go into a settings option on webpage - and toggle options off - close the pop up - reopen the settings and toggle the option back on - close the pop up

Comment: HTML and code should be shared as a text now image. [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: @ZachRuf is your question around avoiding duplicated steps? I can give some approaches if so

Comment: @OPSM - it is - so the scenario above I have the settings opening - and I have to open toggle off then open toggle back on like 10 different toggle options - each I have to toggle off close the window to verify and then open settings toggle back on and close to verify the option is back on screen.